# Код выводит иероглифы

Tags: php, кодировка

Код выводит иероглифы. Почему это происходит и как исправить?

Кодировка: UTF-8 без ВОМ

Вот код:

```
<?php
    class User{
        public $name;
        public $login;
        public $password;

        function __construct($name, $login, $password){
            $this -> name = $name;
            $this -> login = $login;
            $this -> password = $password;
        }
        function __destruct(){
            echo '<br>Пользователь '.$this -> name.' удалён'; 
        }
        public function showInfo(){
            echo '<p>Name: '.$this -> name;
            echo '<br>Login: '.$this -> login;
            echo '<br>Password: '.$this -> password;
        }
    }
    $user1 = new User('John Smith', 'john', '1234');
    $user1 -> showInfo();

    $user2 = new User('Mike Dow', 'mike', '5678');
    $user2 -> showInfo();

    $user3 = new User('Ivan Petrov', 'ivan', '9012');
    $user3 -> showInfo();
    ?>
```

Что выводит:

```
Name: John Smith
Login: john
Password: 1234

Name: Mike Dow
Login: mike
Password: 5678

Name: Ivan Petrov
Login: ivan
Password: 9012
РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ Ivan Petrov СѓРґР°Р»С‘РЅ
РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ Mike Dow СѓРґР°Р»С‘РЅ
РџРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ John Smith СѓРґР°Р»С‘РЅ
```

Comment: не получилось все равно. ни один из вариантов не помог(((

Comment: @Алексей: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. Вы написали ответ, в котором на самом деле нет ответа — так не нужно делать (поэтому я преобразовал его в комментарий). Если хотите, вы можете задать новый вопрос и дать там ссылку на этот, в качестве контекста. Только приведите пример того, как вы пробовали и что не получается, чтобы отвечающие могли воспроизвести вашу проблему.

Comment: @Алексей: Кстати, если вы зарегистрируетесь на сайте, вам будет гораздо удобнее, даже если просто читать его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, дело в различиях кодировки браузера и веб-сервера. Например, сервер отдает текст в utf-8, а браузеру указано обрабатывать в cp-1251. Есть несколько вариантов настройки:

- Указать HTML-тег в контейнере `<head>`: `<meta charset="utf-8">`
- Изменить заголовок HTTP-ответа в PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`
- Задать настройку для Apache с помощью .htaccess: `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8`

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй в начало файла добавить

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```